# consulta SQL para obtener una sumatoria

Tags: mysql

existe alguna manera de conseguir la sumatoria de una tabla llamada numero_inicial, por medio de fechas, para ser mas claro quiero que del año 2011 me muestre el total de numero_inicial de ese año, del año 2012 me muestre el total del numero_inicial y asi sucesivamente

```
SELECT granjas.nombre_granja,año_destete, SUM(numero_inicial) AS total FROM 
formulario_precebo 
INNER JOIN granjas ON granjas.id = formulario_precebo.granja_id WHERE 
granja_id = 9 AND año_destete BETWEEN '2011' AND '2017'
ORDER BY total DESC;
```

la formula que estoy implementando me trae es toda la sumatoria entre ese rango de año, pero yo quiero que me muestre la sumatoria es por cada año.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo he entendido bien lo que necesitas es una agrupación por año.

```
SELECT granja_id ,año_destete,SUM(numero_inicial) as Suma_Anual
FROM formulario_precebo 
INNER JOIN granjas 
  ON granjas.id = formulario_precebo.granja_id 
WHERE 
 año_destete BETWEEN '2011' AND '2017'
group by granja_id ,año_destete
```

Comment: editado para añadir la granja en la agrupación